# can i use google login for my java application?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication

Here i want to developed one application using google account login facility

and i use google app engine for this

any link or any tutorial for this??

Comment: Please take a look at [OpenId](http://openid.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java Users API is documented in full [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/). The overview page includes sample code. Is there anything in particular you're confused about?

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/). There are many tutorials about **google app engine** and two specific on using the **OpenID** throught them..

Comment: but i want to develop in java

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that Python API is quite similar to Java one